# Webpack JS compilation format

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

Good day fellow devs! I just want to ask, if you compile js in webpack, is there a way that the format in the compiled JS file will not be ordered by name?

For example, here are my files:

> display

- display1.js
- display2.js

> events

- events.js

> functions

- functions.js

So I'll import the functions in each js files. So my main.js file looks like this:

```
import * as Functions from './functions/functions.js';
import * as Events from './events/events.js';
import * as DisplayOne from './display/display1.js';
import * as DIsplayTwo from './display/display2.js';

Functions.functionOne();
Functions.functionTwo();
Functions.functionThree();

Events.eventOne();
Events.eventTwo();

DisplayOne.displayOne();

DisplayTwo.displayTwo();
```

But when I go to the compiled main.js by the webpack, the format would be:

```
DisplayOne.displayOne();
DisplayTwo.displayTwo();

Events.eventOne();
Events.eventTwo();

Functions.functionOne();
Functions.functionTwo();
Functions.functionThree();
```

And because of that, there will be errors because there are functions that need to be called first in the displays but the compiled js filed changed it's format from file name first. Just want to know if there's anyway to change the format? Or did I understood the webpack compilation wrong? Is that normal and it should still work? Thank you so much! Sorry I tried my best explaining it lol. Have a great day ahead!

Comment: Normally, webpack will compile all files into a giant array and all import statements into access to this array of functions. Therefore file order does not matter. However, webpack **will never change your code logic**. So if you have an `if()` it will never replace it with a `while()` etc. Similarly it will never re-arrange the lines of code in **a single file**

Comment: .. so no matter how webpack compiles your code, you are responsible for ensuring the order of function calls. But be warned, some of the functions you write may be asynchronous regardless if you are using webpack or not. So the asynchronous functions may finish **after** a function that you call later.